# Dependent variable coding for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, sas

Given the outcome variable in a dataframe is a factored/categorical variable, when regressing the dependent variable (DV) onto a set of independent variables (IVs), what is the model predicting? The probability that the DV is the first level of the factor? Or the second?

A related question: I know that given a numerical column of $1$s and $0$s, a logistic regression would model the probability of the higher order variable (i.e., value=$1$), so I have been attempting to recode the factor "character" variable into a numerical one. I am coming from a SAS background, so I am entirely to used to `if var = "yes" then var_num = 1; else var_num=0;`

That's clearly wrong. What's the most efficient way you have found to recode such variables?

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/categorical-response-variable-prediction/74657#74657

Answer (score 2):

From the help page for `glm` (get it by typing `?glm`)

> A typical predictor has the form response ~ terms where response is
>   the (numeric) response vector and terms is a series of terms which
>   specifies a linear predictor for response. **For binomial and
>   quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor
>   (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or as a
>   two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and
>   failures.** A terms specification of the form first + second indicates
>   all the terms in first together with all the terms in second with any
>   duplicates removed.

and

```
if var = "yes" then var_num = 1; else var_num=0;
```

is in R just

```
var_num <- ifelse(var=="yes", 1, 0)
```